# how to use a FontAwesome icon for openshift template

Tags: css, openshift, font-awesome, openshift-origin, okd

As mentioned in [dev_guide](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/dev_guide/templates.html#writing-description), we can set an icon for an openshift template.

The description for `iconClass` said:

> An icon to be displayed with your template in the web console. Choose from our existing logo icons when possible. You can also use icons from FontAwesome and PatternFly. Alternatively, provide icons through CSS customizations that can be added to an OpenShift Container Platform cluster that uses your template. You must specify an icon class that exists, or it will prevent falling back to the generic icon

when I use default openshift logos like `icon-laravel` it works but I don't know how to use a `FontAwesome` logo.  i tried using `ghost`, `fa fa-ghost` and `fas fa-ghost` as mentioned [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use)  but non of them worked.

how can I use non default logos such as FontAwesome for openshift template ?

---

P.S: I use openshift origin v3.10 and google-chrome v69.0 if it's important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font awesome version 4.7 is available in [openshift-console 3.10](https://github.com/openshift/origin-web-console/blob/release-3.10/bower.json#L62) (and newer), so you would be limited to [these](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/) (`fa fa-snapchat-ghost` is the only "ghost" I found there).